# PyQt5 QLabel.width() Doesn't give the right width

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I need to put 2 labels on the same line but a with spacing between each other, about 15 pixels away from another label. so the y is the same but the x is the first label width + 15.

now I don't know the text that will be in both labels so the width will change according to the text.

The code:

```
  def labels(self):
    # My Username
    self.usernameLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.usernameLabel.setEnabled(True)
    self.usernameLabel.setText("Username: " + self.username)
    self.usernameLabel.setStyleSheet("font-size:11pt")
    self.usernameLabel.move(0,0)
    self.usernameLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
    self.usernameLabel.setObjectName("usernameLabel")
    # The person i am chatting with.
    self.chatUsernameLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.chatUsernameLabel.setEnabled(True)
    self.chatUsernameLabel.setText("Username: " + "Name")
    self.chatUsernameLabel.setStyleSheet("font-size:11pt")
    self.chatUsernameLabel.move(self.usernameLabel.width()+15,0)
    self.chatUsernameLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
    self.chatUsernameLabel.setObjectName("chatUsernameLabel")
```

self.usernameLabel.width() always returns 100, and I checked in the Pyqt Designer, and it's above 100. why do I get this value? and what can I use to get the right value of the label width?

Comment: Does replacing `self.usernameLabel.width()` with `self.usernameLabel.sizeHint()[0]` help?

Comment: @Seon yes! but its self.usernameLabel.sizeHint().width() its not a list but a QSize object, I think. but thanks!

Comment: Indeed, thanks for pointing that out! Glad it helped.

Comment: Alternatively, instead of manually setting the position of the labels you could consider putting them in a QHBoxLayout with a spacer in between.